Trying to understand Ligthill-Whitham traffic model
I am reading this paper, describing an ODE-based traffic model. Initially it starts with a PDE model, which is then simplified to obtain a more tractable ODE one.
I'm trying to understand the initial PDE model. I am new to traffic modeling (and PDEs really), so forgive my ignorance.
The paper, and many resources I found, mention that Ligthill-Whitham models assume the car flow is solely a function of the car density $\rho$, which is supposed to be:

A continuously differentiable, strictly concave function
With value zero when the density is zero (as there are no cars) and when the density is maximal (as the cars are bumper to bumper) -- This maximal density on the $j$-th road of the network is denoted: $\rho_{\max, j}$.

Given such a flow function $f$, the paper states that:

the macroscopic Lighthill–Whitham model for traffic flow on a road j is given by the non-linear conservation law:

$$ \dfrac{\partial \rho_j(x, t)}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial f(\rho_j(x, t))}{\partial x} = 0 $$
For all $x$ in $[a_j, b_j]$ (interval representing the $j$-th road) and $t$ in the time frame considered $[0, T]$, and:
$$ \rho_j(x, 0) = \boxed{\rho_{j, 0}}(x) \quad\quad \forall x \in [a_j, b_j] $$
I do not understand what the boxed term $\rho_{j, 0}$ is. The notation is not introduced anywhere in the paper, so I believe it may be some standard notation I'm not aware of. I believe it may be some boundary or initial condition, but I don't quite get its role.

It is just the initial condition in the $j^{\text{th}}$ interval.

@MatthewCassell thank you. So, in a numerical model, I should just provide those as parameters right?

Yes, though you will also need a boundary condition on each interval.
